# When I type in ifconfig to the command line, what does the information mean?

Tags: ethernet, ifconfig

When I type in **ifconfig** I see a lot of information, what does it mean? Especially the information under the heading eth0.

Comment: Can you be more specific

Comment: Well, I typed ifconfig into the command line and lots of letters and numbers appeared. I want to know what this information stands for/means.

Comment: Can you edit your answer so your question is more specific

Comment: Are you executing commands without even reading what they do before?

Comment: Yes, it is part of an assingment.

Comment: How much investigation did you do yourself? You have a history of just dumping school assignment questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:1d:48:fc:28:5d  
          inet addr:192.168.42.42  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a21d:48ff:fefc:285d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:19743266 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13762352 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:20091618674 (20.0 GB)  TX bytes:4119979239 (4.1 GB)
```

- `eth0` is the name of the interface
- `Link encap` shows the type of layer 1 media, in this case ethernet
- `HWaddr` shows the MAC address of the adapter
- `inet addr` is the IP address of the interface
- `Bcast` is IP address used for broadcast messages (for example, ARP)
- `Mask` is the subnet mask used by the interface
- `inet6 addr` is the IPv6 address of the interface, with the subnet mask (`/64`)
- `Scope` says whether the scope of the IPv6 address is local or global (used in routing)
- `UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST` are flags associated with the interface, in this case it means the IP stack is up, able to broadcast, running and supports multicast.
- `MTU` is the maximum length of ethernet frames
- `Metric` is a priority mechanism used in routing
- `RX packets` are the amount of packets received

  - `errors`: the amount of errors in packets (ie. invalid CRC)
  - `dropped`: the amount of dropped packets (packets received but not destined for machine)
  - `overruns` happen when the kernel can't empty the buffers in time, causing them to overrun
  - `frame` is the number of misaligned frames (the frame is not an integer multiple of bytes)
- `TX packets` is the number of packets transmitted

  - Most fields are same as above
  - `carrier` is a carrier related error (ie. duplex mismatch)
- `collisions` is the number of collisions that occurred
- `txqueuelen` is the size of the transmit queue of the NIC
- `RX/TX bytes` is the number of bytes received/sent

Comment: @TomScott - **So improve the quesiton**

Comment: @TomScott Are you going to tell your teacher that you just copy-pasted the answer off the internet or am I going to go without credit here? I think you're just fooling yourself. If you're not able to figure at least half of this stuff out by just looking at it, you're not going to be able to understand my explanation either.

Comment: @TomScott, unbelievable.  You dump your schoolwork here asking people to do your basic research for you.  mtak volunteers his own time writing a detailed answer for you, and you post that?  Why would anyone answer any of your future questions?